# jquery autosuggestion navigate through hints list

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, autosuggest, hints

I'd like to create searchtoolbar with autosugestion. I don't want to use jquery autocomplete plugin. I have already create script for sending and receiving information from jquery to php and from php to jquery. I have got everything but I want to add a possibility to navigate through hoints' list using arrows. It doesn't work. I think my problem is that jquery can't see dynamically added 'li'. 
Have you got any ideas?

HTML:

```
<section id="search_toolbar_input">
                <section class="searchToolbarResultBox">
                    <ul class="searchToolbarResultBoxList" id="thislist">
                    <li><input placeholder="Szukaj..." type="text" id="topper_search" class="searchToolbar" name="topper_search"></li>
                   </ul>
                </section>
             </section>
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("focus","ul.searchToolbarResultBoxList li",function() {
        var li = $("ul.searchToolbarResultBoxList li");
        var selected;
        $("ul.searchToolbarResultBoxList li").on("keyup",function(e){

            if(e.which == 40)
            {
                $('ul').listview();
                li.eq(1).css('backgroundColor','blue');
                if(selected)
                {
                                    var tmp = selected;
                                    selected.removeClass("selected");
                    selected = tmp.next().addClass("selected");
                }
                else {
                    selected = li.eq(0).addClass("selected");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$("ul.searchToolbarResultBoxList li").on("keyup", function(e){})` with `$("ul.searchToolbarResultBoxList").on("keyup", "li", function(e){})`

This binds the event listener to the ul instead of each li. But events from each li will still "bubble up" to the ul, and `this` will still reference the li.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: It still doesn't work. this is a result: thenetwriters.com/index2.php